# How to add xmpp listeners to services in android?

Tags: android, xmpp, android-service

I am working on a chat(1-to-1) application in Android. I'm using Smack api and jabber on the server.

**Establishing the connection**

Using AsyncTask I do `connection.connect().login();` on application start as or when user session is available. The XMPP `Connection` is provided by dagger.

**XMPP Listeners**

1. Connection Listener (reconnect on break)
2. Message Listener (incoming messages, presence), send notification when app is not is foreground.

My initial thought was to set up an IntentService containing the message listeners, but I'm not sure how to set up IntentServices as a long running task the runs indefinitely on app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In service you can check the connection and he it disconnect then try to attempt for again login. Please refer below code.Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public static final String ACTION_LOGGED_IN = "chatapp.loggedin";
private final LocalBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
XMPP xmppConnection;
private MessageHandler messageHandler;
private static String TAG = "MyService";


private void onLoggedIn() {

    FromMatchesFilter localFromMatchesFilter = null;
    try {
        localFromMatchesFilter = new FromMatchesFilter(JidCreate.domainBareFrom(Domainpart.from("livegroup@chatapp." + Common.SERVER_HOST)), false);
    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(messageHandler == null){
        messageHandler = new MessageHandler(this);
    }

   XMPP.getInstance().addStanzaListener(this, messageHandler);

    XMPP.getInstance().addChatListener(this, new ChatManagerListener() {
        @Override
        public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {

        }
    });

    XMPP.getInstance().configureSrvDeliveryManager(this);

    if(XMPP.getInstance().isFileTransferNegotiatorServiceEnabled()){
        PurplkiteLogs.logError(TAG, "File Transfer Service is enabled");
    }
    FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY = true;

}


public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (MyService.class.getName().equals(
                service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public XMPP XMPP() {
    return this.xmppConnection;
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent paramIntent) {
    return this.binder;
}

Handler holdConnectionHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        PurplkiteLogs.logInfo(TAG, "Service Handler Running");
        checkUserLogin();
        holdConnectionHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 10 * 1000);
    }
};

private void checkUserLogin() {
    String user = AppSettings.getUser(MyService.this);

                XMPPTCPConnection connection = XMPP.getInstance().getConnection(MyService.this);
                if(connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                if(XMPP.getInstance().isConnected()){
                    XMPP.getInstance().close();
                }
                final String user = AppSettings.getUser(MyService.this);
                final String pass = AppSettings.getPassword(MyService.this);
                final String username = AppSettings.getUserName(MyService.this);
                try {
                    XMPP.getInstance().login(user, pass, username);
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (PurplKiteXMPPConnectException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}


public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    PurplkiteLogs.logDebug(TAG, "in onCreate of Service");
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    this.xmppConnection = XMPP.getInstance();
    holdConnectionHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context paramAnonymousContext,
                              Intent paramAnonymousIntent) {
            MyService.this.onLoggedIn();
        }
    }, new IntentFilter("chatapp.loggedin"));

    if ((AppSettings.getUser(this) != null)
            && (AppSettings.getPassword(this) != null)) {
        final String user = AppSettings.getUser(this);
        final String pass = AppSettings.getPassword(this);
        final String username = AppSettings
                .getUserName(MyService.this);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    XMPPTCPConnection connection=  MyService.this.xmppConnection.getConnection(MyService.this);
                    if(connection == null || !connection.isAuthenticated()){
                        MyService.this.xmppConnection.login(user, pass,
                                username);
                    }
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    PurplkiteLogs.logError(TAG, "Error in Login");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (SmackException e) {
                    PurplkiteLogs.logError(TAG, "Error in Login");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    PurplkiteLogs.logError(TAG, "Error in Login");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    PurplkiteLogs.logError(TAG, "Error in Login");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (PurplKiteXMPPConnectException e) {
                    PurplkiteLogs.logError(TAG, "Error in Login");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MyService.this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                        "chatapp.loggedin"));
                return;
            }
        }).start();
    }

}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public LocalBinder() {
    }

    public MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks